# General Problems with Hover Transitions

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, transition

I am having some trouble with hover transitions. I have a fullwidth bar of 13 images. When you hover over them, some text appears depending on which one you hover over. I would like to slow down the transition time, and also make it so the images go opaque at the same time the image slides up (currently it slides up and then goes opaque). And if at all possible, it would be neat to have an image stay "hovered" until one of the other images is hovered. One more thing, it gets a little jittery if you hover near the bottom of an image and move the cursor left or right, hopefully this can be fixed too.

What I have so far is on this page: http://homeinspectioncarync.com/testpage/

Following is the CSS and HTML I've used. Sorry for the one-line HTML, I couldn't quite figure out how to format that correctly in here. It follows the same pattern though img1 /img p1 /p img2 /img p2 /p and so on until it gets to 13. I know the community here is great so any help is appreciated!

CSS:

```
.images {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.images:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: -10px;
}

.para {
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
  top: 200px;
  font-size: 200%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#one:hover + #pone {
  visibility: visible;
}

#two:hover + #ptwo {
  visibility: visible;
}

#three:hover + #pthree {
  visibility: visible;
}

etc. (until 13)
```

HTML:

```
<img src = "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/00c/2ab/35ae340.jpg" class = "images" id = "one"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "pone">1</p>
<img src = "http://homeinspectionraleighnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Glenns-Photo-1.png" class = "images" id = "two" style = "left: 100px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "ptwo">2</p>
<img src = "https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/18718_2753855091076_8128390731521222770_n.jpg?oh=d1d49aea28d3cb6ff76033db1ae056ba&oe=57D998E2" class = "images" id = "three" style = "left: 200px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "pthree">3</p>
<img src = "https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c22.22.272.272/s160x160/166620_1817593049535_5878435_n.jpg?oh=78d8a42398b126fc1f75d1b32295029a&oe=57D73E8C" class = "images" id = "four" style = "left: 300px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "pfour">4</p>
<img src = "http://homeinspectioncarync.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/trevor-e1464897672300.jpg" class = "images" id = "five" style = "left: 400px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "pfive">5</p>
<img src = "http://homeinspectioncarync.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/betterrob-e1464897851528.jpg" class = "images" id = "six" style = "left: 500px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "psix">6</p>
<img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class = "images" id = "seven" style = "left: 600px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "pseven">7</p>
<img src = "https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12373154_1629529113976977_749911928470317591_n.jpg?oh=70dc625bdbd6c6e35406f47cc02bd82e&oe=57D42D84" class = "images" id = "eight" style = "left: 700px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "peight">8</p>
<img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class = "images" id = "nine" style = "left: 800px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "pnine">9</p>
<img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class = "images" id = "ten" style = "left: 900px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "pten">10</p>
<img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class = "images" id = "eleven" style = "left: 1000px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "peleven">11</p>
<img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class = "images" id = "twelve" style = "left: 1100px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "ptwelve">12</p>
<img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class = "images" id = "thirteen" style = "left: 1200px;"></img>
<p class = "para" id = "pthirteen">13</p>
```

Comment: Just a heads up that you'll want to remove the closing `</img>` tags, as these are not necessary / incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main reason the two animations weren't activating at the same time is that `transition` only works when the non-hover state has the property defined that will be animated in the `hover` state. In your case, you were missing an initial declaration of the `top` property (thus that wasn't animating). I adjusted things a little to use `transform` instead, as this provides a smoother transition.

I also wrapped each image and paragraph in a container (which will fix the jittery issues you were seeing), because the image will animate independent of the container and won't be handling the hover event. In addition, I cleaned up quite a bit of markup. See my comments below for best practices there.

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
  
.images {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.image-container:hover .images {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.para {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 200%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.image-container:hover .para {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/00c/2ab/35ae340.jpg" class="images">
  <p class="para">1</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://homeinspectionraleighnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Glenns-Photo-1.png" class="images">
  <p class="para">2</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/18718_2753855091076_8128390731521222770_n.jpg?oh=d1d49aea28d3cb6ff76033db1ae056ba&oe=57D998E2" class="images">
  <p class="para">3</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c22.22.272.272/s160x160/166620_1817593049535_5878435_n.jpg?oh=78d8a42398b126fc1f75d1b32295029a&oe=57D73E8C" class="images">
  <p class="para">4</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://homeinspectioncarync.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/trevor-e1464897672300.jpg" class="images">
  <p class="para">5</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://homeinspectioncarync.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/betterrob-e1464897851528.jpg" class="images">
  <p class="para">6</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class="images">
  <p class="para">7</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12373154_1629529113976977_749911928470317591_n.jpg?oh=70dc625bdbd6c6e35406f47cc02bd82e&oe=57D42D84" class="images">
  <p class="para">8</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class="images">
  <p class="para">9</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class="images">
  <p class="para">10</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class="images">
  <p class="para">11</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class="images">
  <p class="para">12</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png" class="images">
  <p class="para">13</p>
</div>
```

A couple good rules of thumb, after looking through your markup:

- Only use ID's when they are absolutely necessary (if you're targeting them with JavaScript, and if there really will only be one ever).
- Use absolute positioning sparingly. With your original code, creating a responsive page would be almost impossible since all the elements were stuck in one place. Instead, keep parent elements in the flow and absolute elements closely coupled.
- Make sure that html attributes are syntactically correct. You were writing `class = "images"`. Update to `class="images"`.
- No inline styling. It makes it very difficult to update the page later.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for all of that. I go to a University for Computer Science but haven't taken a course on anything involving web design so I definitely am interested in the rules of thumb and standard practices

Answer (score 1):

Those two transitions are happening at the same time. It just seems like the color change is happening after the slide up because the transition time is happening over time as opposed to instantly with the slide.

And if you want to make the transition slower, just change the value in the transition property from 1000ms to something higher. You can use 's' for seconds as well eg. 1s, 2s etc.

Also, instead of creating a separate CSS definition for each ID of each image, use a class that can be applied to all of them, since they all have the same behavior.

Ps. Please use codepen or some similar online code viewer next time you have a question like this. It's much easier to help that way.

Comment: I thought it was helpful, not sure who downvoted. Thanks for the info!

Comment: How could I make a class that can apply to all of them? Pic1's text should only appear when Pic1 is hovered. I feel like if they were all a part of one class, then all the picture's text would appear when any of the pictures is hovered.

Comment: Based on your current HTML/CSS you could do .images:hover + p. It will select the <p> tag directly after an element of class 'images' that is being hovered over.
`.images:hover + p {
  visibility: visible;
 }`


Created a pen for you: http://codepen.io/alanqthomas/pen/EyjmoE

Comment: now that you say it it seems so obvious. Thanks for the insight